# How I search all the occurrence of a substring of a string and store the valuenext to that substring to a variable in python?

Tags: python, string, search

`string s1 = "abc:12 Hellow world abc :342 hi there abc :15`
Here,in python,I want to search all `'abc'` and store the value after semicolon. To be more specific ,if I search `'abc'` substring,then `12;342;15` value would be stored in variable.

Answer (score 0):

this regex finds all `abc<optional whitespaces>:<optional whitespace><value>` where `<value>` must not contain whitespace characters or quotes...

```
import re
data = """
string s1 = "abc:12 Hellow world abc :342 hi there abc :15"
"""

l = re.findall(r'abc\s*:\s*([^\s\"\']+)', data)
print(l)
```

`l` is your list of values and holds `['12', '342', '15']`

according to your specification, this is not restricted to numerical values (you might want to adapt the regex if your values can only be integer numbers)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```py
import re

string = "abc:12 Hellow world abc :342 hi there abc :15"
pattern = re.compile(r"abc.*?:(.+?)\b")
matches = pattern.findall(string)

print(matches) # ['12', '342', '15']
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/gAQwVs/1

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

**Based on you'r input!**

```
 a = [int(x.split(" ")[0][1:]) for x in s1.split("abc")[1:]]
 print(a)
```

**Output**

```
 [12, 342, 15]
```